# Active / Inactive states

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I'm looking to add an inactive state to an accordion title that isn't labeled with the class "active".

```
$(".accordion-section-title").click(function() {
  if (!$(".accordion-section-title").hasClass('active')) {
    $(".accordion-section-title").toggleClass("inactive");
  }
});
```

Comment: I am not getting your actual problem. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Hi Eshu. I'll try and restate it a different way. I'm working with an accordion menu for example. When I click one of the accordion options, I want the active state class that is currently inserted to the open section of the accordion to trigger the other segments to toggle on the class "inactive". Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be below code will help you out:

```
$(".accordion-section-title").click(function(evt) {
        $(".accordion-section-title").removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
        $(evt.currentTarget).addClass('active');
});
```

Please let me know if you still face any issue.